# What does it mean that a pan is "anti jamming"?

Tags: language

Lots of shops call their food pans "anti-jamming", but I have not been able to find out what that means.

I don't think it's related to radio communication or making fruit jam :)

Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These pans (sometimes called *chafing dishes*) are designed to fit into a frame above water and a heat source to keep food hot. They are advertising that their pans won't get stuck (jam) in the frame.

As evidence, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oivmeo4WO6E) (and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLi1MkAJc4o)), which shows how even after pressure is applied the pan does not require effort to remove from the frame. (I found the video [here](http://www.tradekorea.com/product/detail/P594001/GN-pan-with-handles-anti-jamming-and-electro-polishing.html), on a tradeKorea page advertising a similar pan, and it was produced by an account called 'ChefPro'.)

Comment: Even more impressive would be if they wouldn't get stuck when you make a stack of them.  (as you can achieve the frame issue by just making sure they're undersized)

Comment: As Joe says, "non - jam - while - self - stacking" is a real engineering achievement.

Comment: What if you stack them while they're coated with jam and then wait a few months?

Comment: I've had them jam on me many years ago when I worked in food service, pretty annoying when you're in a hurry, and their contents can spill all over when they come unstuck.

Comment: Also to note, heat can cause the expansion of the pans in general, and these pans are advertising that even despite that they will not jam.

Answer (score 5):

I refers to the fact that they won't jam up when stacked together.

ANTI-JAM STACKING LUGS - Each stainless steel steam table pan features anti-jam stacking lugs, so it won't stick to other pans when you take it out of storage. This feature allows you to save space by stacking pans without worrying about a hassle the next time you want to use them.

Comment: This has been my personal experience. I've never had a hotel pan (what they call them on the west coast of the U.S). jam in a steam table. Stacking them is another story altogether.